# Pivot one column with multiple rows into to one concatenated row

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, pivot

I need to prepare a list of emails tat can be copy and pasted into the email field (2.5k).

I have one column with one email address in each row.
I need the end result to look like:
email1@test.com; email2@test.com; email3@test.com

```
Select *
        from(
        Select   email, 1 as num
        FROM tabl1
        WHERE  b.stu_cde = 1 ) e
        Pivot( max(email) 
        for num in ([1]) )as pv
```

Comment: Hint try `STUFF`. And second thing SO is not a code writing service, Please share what you have tried so far. there are 100's of answer available only on SO for this question. And `sql` is language it is not clear you are talking about which platform i,e; `mysql`, `sql-server`, `plsql` etc. Please mention proper tag.

Comment: What database are you using (e.g MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.) ?  "SQL" is just a language, not an actual product.

Comment: Hint:  Update to a supported version of SQL Server and use `string_agg()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Instead of `pivot` use `stuff` to get your result. For more details about pivot please find this link [PIVOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017).

```
 select Stuff( (select ';' + email from tabl1 for xml path('')),1,1,'') as Result
```

Comment: That worked a charm, how ever the result is too long, is there a way i can break it up into say five groupings?